# Can't uninstall games i downloaded from steam Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, steam

I'm relatively new to linux and more specifically Ubuntu and I'm having this weird issue where I am unable to uninstall games in steam. I'll right-click to uninstall but when i do it just gives me the progress bar over and over and never actually uninstalls the game. I'm running Ubuntu 20.04 with cinnamon.I've tried fully closing and re-launching steam thought every time i did that it still gave me the same thing. Any help is greatly appreciated! [uninstall issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SRi0E.png)

Comment: same problem. cant uninstall

Answer (score 2):

I have had the same problem. Inside Steam, on the page of a game, there is this button on the right, which seemingly allows one to uninstall the game as one of its options. However, this menu entry does nothing.

It also will not work when right-clicking the game in the overview on the left side.

However, there are two ways which work:

1. In big picture mode, all buttons work. There is a button top right which enters that mode.
2. Choose "settings" from top left. There is one option which lets you uninstall games. The name is "Speicherplatz" ("storage space") in German. (I can not tell you the English name, as the drop-down to choose the interface language is also broken, lol) Select the game you want to uninstall, and then click "uninstall".

**I wonder If Valve is aware how many buttons do not work in their Linux GUI.**

Comment: Thanks. Works as of 2023-10-02.

Comment: @spawn I guess you mean "the workaround works" and not "the previously broken buttons now work". Because they do not.

Comment: Indeed. Your workaround works, steam is still broken (;

Comment: Thank you for this answer, low score though it has.  This issue has been bugging the tar out of me, and I was actually running out of disk space.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you're not running any of the games and then try this:

```
steamcmd +apps_installed +quit
```

This will list all the applications installed using steam. find your application id and try this command:

```
steamcmd +app_uninstall appid-complete +quit
```

Replace `appid` with the one you need from the list you've got from running the previous command.

Let us know if you're successfull.

Comment: Hi! i tried this in terminal and it gave me this error saying 'steamcmd: command not found` . is there any way around this? [terminal screenshot] (https://imgur.com/a/2ZRaWD9)

Comment: Sorry, you need to install it separately. Check the instructions [here](https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/SteamCMD#Package_from_repositories) for Ubuntu/Debian